# Trying to create a custom polymer component using ag-grid

Tags: ajax, polymer, ag-grid

I am trying to create a custom polymer component that accesses data from a remote server.  The data is returned in the following JSON format:

```
[
{
    "source": "northwind",
    "databasetype": "MySQL",
    "classname": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost/northwind",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root"
},
{
    "source": "Oracle Sample HR Database",
    "databasetype": "Oracle",
    "classname": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
    "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl",
    "username": "hr",
    "password": "oracle"
}
]
```

I have the following custom component started:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-example">

  <template>

    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <iron-ajax
      auto
      id="ajaxGetSources"
      url="/modules/get-sources.xqy"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{sourcelist}}"></iron-ajax>
    <ag-grid id="myGrid"></ag-grid>
  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'my-example',

      properties: {
        sourcelist: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true
        }
      },

      ready: function() {
      }

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Has anyone done this before?  I am looking for an example of ag-grid that is for a polymer 1.0 component.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are asking about?

Comment: I do not know where to add:// get ag-Grid to install the web component
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithWebComponents(); and var myGrid = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
myGrid.setGridOptions(gridOptions);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Setup

First, you'll need to import the JS and CSS for `ag-grid` in your element HTML.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/4.1.5/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/4.1.5/styles/ag-grid.css">
```

Then, setup `ag-grid`'s initialization and clean-up in your Polymer object's `attached` and `detached` callbacks, respectively. In `attached`, make sure to call `agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithWebComponents()`, and to initialize the grid, specifying columns with `field` names that correspond to the data fields you'd like to extract from the incoming data. In `detached`, make sure to destroy the grid to avoid memory leaks.

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>...</template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',
      attached: function() {
        agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithWebComponents();

        var columnDefs = [
          {headerName: "Source", field: "source"},
          {headerName: "Database Type", field: "databasetype"},
          {headerName: "Class", field: "classname"}
        ];

        var gridOptions = {
          columnDefs: columnDefs
        };

        this.$.myGrid.setGridOptions(gridOptions);
      },
      detached: function() {
        this.$.myGrid.api.destroy();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now, you have a few options to populate your grid.

#### Option 1: Pass-through data binding

When dealing with AJAX data that needs no modification, you can simply pass the incoming data to `ag-grid`.

In your Polymer template's `iron-ajax`, bind the response to a property e.g., named `rowData`, and pass that to `ag-grid` via its `row-data` property. Note that we do not need to declare `rowData` as a property on the Polymer object (it's done automatically).

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax
        url="/modules/get-sources.xqy"
        last-response="{{rowData}}"
        ...
        >
    </iron-ajax>
    <ag-grid id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh" row-data="[[rowData]]"></ag-grid>
  </template>
  <script>...</script>
</dom-module>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pupeqi/edit?html,output)</sup>

#### Option 2: Relayed data binding

If you need to modify the incoming data (e.g., to filter only NorthWind data), you could use a data-handling callback with `iron-ajax`.

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax
        url="/modules/get-sources.xqy"
        on-response="handleData"
        ...
        >
    </iron-ajax>
    <ag-grid id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh" row-data="[[rowData]]"></ag-grid>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',
      handleData: function(e) {
        var resp = e.detail.response;
        if (resp) {
          this.rowData = resp.filter(function(item) {
            return item.source === 'northwind';
          });
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/neruku/edit?html,output)</sup>

#### Option 3: Set data directly (without binding)

Alternatively, you could modify the grid's row data directly without defining a property on the Polymer object. You'd remove the data binding from `ag-grid` in the template, and then assign the row data directly to `this.$.myGrid.rowData`.

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax
        url="/modules/get-sources.xqy"
        on-response="handleData"
        ...
        >
    </iron-ajax>
    <ag-grid id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh"></ag-grid>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',
      handleData: function(e) {
        var resp = e.detail.response;
        if (resp) {
          this.$.myGrid.rowData = resp.filter(function(item) {
            return item.source === 'northwind';
          });
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/suhici/edit?html,output)</sup>

Comment: The one thing that needed to be corrected is that the shadow dom did not import the css, so I copied the content of the css files into the style tag in my component.